# Selected Index changed doesnt fire

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down list that is populated on page load and by default the selected index is 0 and its set to an emty string.  On page load if we change the selected value the selected index method doesnt fire.

```
 if(!page.isPostback)
    {
      this.ddl.DataSource = list;
      this.ddl.DataValueField = "Id";
      this.ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
      this.ddl.DataBind();
      this.ddl.Items.Insert(0, String.Empty);

      if (Request.QueryString != null)
      {
           string name = Request.QueryString["name"];
           long Id = list.Where(item => item.Name == name).Select(item =>item.Id).SingleOrDefault();
           this.selectedIndex = 1;
           this.ddl.SelectedValue = Id.ToString();
      }

    }
```

Comment: Is `AutoPostback` set to true?

Comment: As Bala R suggested, I would make sure that `AutoPostBack` is true. Also, what is this doing?: `this.selectedIndex = 1` Is it setting the selected index of the DropDown?? Should it be `this.ddl.SelectedIndex = 1`?

Comment: See answer, it has nothing to do with autopostback. The problem is that the event will only be triggered if it happens on the client.

Answer (score 1):

That's as it should be. If you want to execute some piece of logic from both the event and/or from page load, put that logic in a separate method so you can call it easily from your page load.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void BindList()
        {
                this.ddl.Items.Clear();
                this.ddl.DataSource = list;
                this.ddl.DataValueField = "Id";
                this.ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
                this.ddl.DataBind();
                this.ddl.Items.Insert(0, String.Empty);
                this.ddl.Items.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

---

```
if(!page.isPostback)
    {

      BindList();
      if (Request.QueryString != null)
      {
           string name = Request.QueryString["name"];
           long Id = list.Where(item => item.Name == name).Select(item =>item.Id).SingleOrDefault();
           this.ddl.Items.ClearSelection();
           this.ddl.Items.FindByValue(Id.ToString()).Selected = true;
      }

    }
```